# Problema relaciones usando sequelize , express node y mySql

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, sequelize.js

estoy tranaando de crear las relaciones y hacer un findAll para obtener los productos relacionados con las categoria(category), company y colors pero estoy teniendo problemas.
Las tablas se crearon correctamente y verifique el la parte visual de Mysql y se puede obeservar en la tabla product que las llaves foráneas se han creado correctamente para los campos company_id y category_id.

Modelos:
Nota: el import de sequelize tiene la connecion a la base de datos.

**company**

```
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../connection.js';

export class Company extends Model {
  static associate(models){
    Company.hasMany(models.product,{
      foreignKey:'company_id'
    })
  }
}

Company.init(
  {
    company_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    company_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    company_contact: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: true,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'Company' }
);

Company.sync()
```

**Category**

```
import { sequelize } from "../connection.js";
import { DataTypes,Model } from "sequelize";

export class Category extends Model{
    static associate(models){
        Category.hasMany(models.product,{
            foreignKey:'category_id'
        })
    }
}

Category.init({
    category_id:{
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement:true,
        primaryKey:true,
        allowNull:false
    },
    category_name:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false
    }
},{
    sequelize,
    modelName:'Category'
})

Category.sync()
```

**Tabla intermedia de product  colors** en relacion muchos a muchos

```
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../connection.js';

export class ProductColors extends Model {
  
}

ProductColors.init(
  {
    product_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    colors_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'ProductColors' }
);

ProductColors.sync()
```

**model colors**

```
import { sequelize } from "../connection.js";
import { Model,DataTypes } from "sequelize";

export class Colors extends Model{
    static associate(models){
        Colors.belongsToMany(models.Product,{
            through:models.ProductColors
        }) 
    }
}

Colors.init({
    color_id:{
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement:true,
        primaryKey:true
    },
    color_type:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false
    }
},{sequelize,modelName:'Colors'})

await Colors.sync()
```

**model product**

```
import { Model,DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

import { sequelize } from '../connection.js';


  export class Product extends Model{
    static associate(models){
      Product.belongsTo(models.Category,{
        foreignKey:'category_id',
      })

      Product.belongsTo(models.Company,{
        foreignKey:'company_id'
      })

      Product.belongsToMany(models.Colors,{
        through:models.ProductColors
      }) 
    }
  }
  

  //datos o campos de nuestra tabla
   Product.init({
    product_id:{
        type:DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey:true
    },
    product_name:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
    },
    price:{
        type:DataTypes.FLOAT(10,2),
        allowNull:false
    },
    isStock:{
        type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    },
    company_id:{
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNulle:false,
      references:{
        model:'Companies',
        key:'company_id'
      },
      onDelete:'CASCADE',
      onUpdate:'CASCADE'
    },
    category_id:{
      type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull:false,
      references:{
        model:'Categories',
        key:'category_id'
      }
    }
  },{
    sequelize,
    modelName:"Product"
  })

  Product.sync()
```

**Controlador o ruta**
he tradado con todos los modelos en el include, y me da un error: Product is not associated with 'nombre del modelo que le paso en el include', me da el mismo error con todas.

```
router.get('/product',async(req,res)=>{
    const products =await Product.findAll({
        include:Category
    })
    res.status(200).json({
        status:200,
        ok:true,
        body:{products}
    })
});
```

**Tabla products, se observa lalves foraneas correctamente en mySql**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**tambien estoy teniendo problemas al insertar los elementos con las relaciones, ejemplo yn producto con varios colores directamente.**

Estoy aprendiendo apenas a usar sequelize y tengo varios dias trabajo en este punto.
gracias de antemano.